# Custom 503 page in htaccess to "/path/to/index.php?maintenance"?

Tags: php, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I have a mobile website that I use in conjunction with QR codes on our business cards. At the moment, when I put my main website in maintenance, I use a 503 redirect to maintenance.php. But that also takes out the mobile website. What I would like to achieve is that my mobile website and all the files and folders within that directory (/qr/) are still accessible while in maintenance mode. Additionally, I want to redirect visitors to my mobile business card and show them a message that they are visiting a substitute website.

My mobile business card is located at mydomain.com/qr/. I added this after the `<body>` tag of my /qr/index.php:

```
<?php if(isset($_GET["maintenance"])) {
header('HTTP/1.1 503 Service Temporarily Unavailable');
echo '<div class="maintenance">Our website is currently undergoing maintenance. You are now viewing our mobile business card as a substitute. Our apologies for any inconvenience, we will be back shortly.</div>';
}
else{}
?>
```

So I want my 503 error page to be `mydomain.com/qr/?cp=xxxxx&maintenance` (I need the `cp` for other things).

Among one of the things I've tried, is that I've set the following as my .htaccess in the root folder:

```
RewriteEngine On

Alias /qr/index\.php "/qr/index.php?cp=xxxxx&maintenance"

RewriteCond %{REMOTE_ADDR} !^xxx\.xxx\.xxx\.xxx$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !/qr/$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !\.(css|png|vcf)$
RewriteRule .* /qr/index\.php [L]
```

But I get returned a 500 Internal Server Error. I've read somewhere that `/path/to/503.php` needs to be in an alias, hence my reason to do that.

What am I doing wrong, and how can I achieve my desired result?

Cheers,

Webgremlin

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What's wrong with using error document?

```
ErrorDocument 503 /qr/index.php?cp=xxxxx&maintenance
```

Comment: Thanks. I have no clue why I have not tried that, works perfectly. I had to set `<base href="http://www.mydomain.com/qr/" />` in the `<head></head>` tags of my index document to make the images and css work. I suppose I don't need the `header` anymore in my `if` statement in my index.php?

Answer (score 4):

Using Jon's tip, I got my desired result by changing my htaccess to this:

```
#BEGIN 503 Maintenance
ErrorDocument 503 /qr/index.php?cp=xxxxx&maintenance
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REMOTE_ADDR} !^xxx\.xxx\.xxx\.xxx$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/qr/.*$
RewriteRule .* - [R=503,L]
#EINDE 503 Maintenance
```

I also had to add `<base href="http://www.mydomain.com/qr/" />` to the head of my /qr/index.php file. Otherwise it would try to load my css and images from mydomain.com/style.css and mydomain.com/images rather than from mydomain.com/qr/.

Hope this helps someone.

Answer (score 1):

You're getting the error because `Alias` command isn't allowed in .htaccess. It can only be placed in Apache config like `httpd.conf`.